# Showing that $\int_C 1\ dz = 2 \pi r$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be a circle centered at $a$ of radius $r$.  Parameterize $\gamma$ via $\gamma(t) = a + re^{it}$ on $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$.  This yields us that $\gamma'(t) = ire^{it}$.  I suspect the line integral of $\int_\gamma 1\ dz$ should be $2\pi r$.  How does one finish the equation below?

$$
\int_C 1\ d z = \int_0^{2 \pi} 1(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t)\ dt =  \int_0^{2 \pi} 1 \cdot ri e^{it}\ dt = \underbrace{\ldots}_{\text{?}} = 2 \pi r
$$

Comment: Hint 1: What's the antiderivative of $rie^{it}$?  Hint 2: the answer isn't $2\pi r$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the antiderivative is.

Comment: The answer is most definitely not $2\pi r$. There are a couple of ways to see this. Firstly, $1$ is a holomorphic function so it has a holomorphic antiderivative. Then you could try "plugging in" endpoints for your curve (based on your parameterization). You could also note this from vector calculus. You're doing a line integral as opposed to a regular Riemann integral from basic calculus. From vector calculus, we know that the closed line integral of a "nice" function is zero.

Comment: @Tang A now deleted answer was explaining how to rewrite your complex integral in terms of a sum of real integrals, to which you replied you didn't know how to evaluate. If you don't know how to evaluate real integrals, you definitely have to give us some idea of your background; introductory calculus will certainly be assumed by anyone answering a complex analysis question.